# プログラミング言語を変換できるツールは存在するのでしょうか？

Tags: プログラミング言語

言語変換できるツールのようなものは存在するのでしょうか？

```
例：
Java System.out.println（aaaa）;
↑↓
PHP  var_dump($aaa);
```

このような形で翻訳してくれるツールがあったら教えていただきたいです。
また、僕は欲しいなと思いますが、必要と感じますでしょうか？

Comment: translator、conveter辺りと言語名で検索するといくつか出てきますね。実用に耐えうるものかは分かりません。

言語変換できるツールは個人的には魅力を感じません。せっかく別の言語で書くなら、その言語らしい書き方にしたいと思います。

Android(Java)から、iOS(Swift)に変換する等ニーズがあるのは分かります。

Comment: 今だと `transpiler` で検索するのが良いです。 英語ですが、こことか http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler 俯瞰できてよいでしょう。

Comment: @MIURAYasuyuki 僕もファイル全体、プロジェクト全体の言語変換については魅力を感じないのは賛成です。ただ、自分の知らない言語を学ぶ際に基本的なデバッグをするためのコードや、よく使うコードなどはすぐに知れるようにしておきたいなと思っております。

Comment: @KoRoN 情報が集まっていて見やすかったです。WEBサービスで横断的に検索できるようなものはなさそうですね。

Comment: それはツールを使うのではなく、「(書きたい言語) (元の関数名ないし処理)」でGoogle検索してもよいのでは…。

Comment: @unarist  今は Google で検索しているのですが、もう少し便利にならないかなと思い投稿してみました

Answer (score 2):

コメントを見ていると言語AからBへのコンパイラというより，言語Aを知ってる時に言語Bでどう書くのか知りたい，というような感じのニーズなのでしょうか．

であればおそらくツールというよりはコードの集積のほうが目的にかなっていて（それぞれの言語"らしい"書き方というようなのもありますので），例えば[Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) あたりが適任なのではないかと思います．

言語Aから言語Bへのコンパイラ/コンバータという観点から言うと他の方が挙げておられるとおりちょくちょくありますね．特にたとえば javascript への変換は[かなりの数があるようです](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS).

Comment: Rosetta code、Fizzbuzzの書き方など基本構文が乗っていてかなりいいなと思いました！

Answer (score 1):

少し本来の回答とは違ってきますが [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) という言語はどうでしょうか
Java PHP からの変換はできませんが Haxe から Java PHP などに変換できます

Comment: ちょっと見てみたいと思います。
新しい言語が出てきた時に、今まで使ってたやつだとこういう書き方っていうのを検索できたらいいなと思っております。

Answer (score 1):

限定的ですが、以下の様なものがあるようです。

米Google、JavaコードをObjective-Cに変換するツール「J2ObjC」を公開
http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/news/201209/18/j2objc.html

https://github.com/google/j2objc

私のまわりでは使われている話は聞いたことがありませんが、
現在もメンテナンスされているので、もしかしたら実用に耐えるものになっているのかもしれません。
ただし、利用するにはMacが必要です。

Comment: なるほど、プロジェクト単位で変換できるツールなんですね。
ちょっとした記述を横断的に翻訳するツールはあんまりないのかもしれませんね。